# Raspberry pi is not showing on network/router's admin page

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

i have a raspberry pi 4b with raspbian bullseye 32 bit os , i was trying to connect it with a hidden network, pi is connected with the network but i can't see it in the "connected device " section of my router,i confirmed that my pi is connected to the interenet,i also have tailscale installed in my pi, talescale is also not showing that pi is connected until i make network visible , is there anyone who can help me , i am now unable to think what's wrong .

Comment: what does this mean? `its not showing up there`

Comment: not showing connected with the network in the admin page

Comment: Try writing in sentences. Describe WHAT YOU HAVE tried - complete with diagnostics.